# Cannot deploy nodejs application with error "NoMethodError: undefined method `owner' for Chef::Resource::DeployRevision"

Tags: chef-recipe, chef-solo, cookbook

I cannot deploy a nodejs app with application & application_nodejs cookbook.

My environment :

1. Chef 11.12.2
2. Application cookbook : 4.1.4
3. Application_nodejs cookbook : 2.0.1
4. Ubuntu : 12.04 LTS

Full error : 
"[2014-06-02T10:51:51+00:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
[2014-06-02T10:51:51+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2014-06-02T10:51:51+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2014-06-02T10:51:51+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2014-06-02T10:51:51+00:00] ERROR: deploy_revision(xxxx) had an error: NoMethodError: undefined method `owner' for Chef::Resource::DeployRevision
[2014-06-02T10:51:51+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)"

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you maybe making a mistake in passing in an empty value. Check that "owner" is actually set with the right value and not a nil.

Comment: thanks for your reply. the "owner" has a value. Let me check more.